# python paraview how to get the color map range min and max values

Tags: python, paraview

Hi I'm looking the method that let me get the actual color map range (min and max) values or the (min and max) scene values. I need to change the range scale value based on this values using something like `RescaleTransferFunction(min, max)` where min and max values are set based on the actual scale values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say you have a data source `s`. You can find the data range values from `s` with the following:

```
info = s.GetDataInformation().DataInformation
arrayInfo = info.GetArrayInformation("Normals", vtk.vtkDataObject.FIELD_ASSOCIATION_POINTS)
range = arrayInfo.GetComponentRange(0)
```

Once you get the data range, you can set the scalar bar range with

```
tf = GetColorTransferFunction("Normals")
tf.RescaleTransferFunction(range[0], range[1])
op = GetOpacityTransferFunction("Normals")
op.RescaleTransferFunction(range[0], range[1])
```